# PlayOnLinux installation scripts never load

Tags: playonlinux, official-repositories

I've installed PlayOnLinux from the official Ubuntu package repositories. It mostly works fine but it seems that it's unable to fetch any installation script.

.

Clicking on *Install program* results in an infitine loading screen and I always have to use the "Install a non-listed program" option:

[image: loading screen]

.

Trying to install anything from the *Components and Functions* submenu results in a long loading (5 minutes at least) and then a message announcing that the checksum of the script is wrong and I have to check the script before running it. The script is always empty:

[image: window showing an empty script]

I've managed to install VB 6 Runtime using the PlayOnLinux console with the command `POL_Call POL_Install_vbrun6` but it took very long to complete.

How do I fix this? Where do I announce this bug?

Comment: is play on linux accomplishing something for you that couldn't be accomplished with Lutris : https://lutris.net/games/ ? POL is starting to be an outdated solution by comparison.

Comment: I already have quite a lot of games installed in my PlayOnLinux virtual drives and I don't want to reinstall them elsewhere, so a way to fix POL would be nice. However thanks for the tip, I'll definitely try Lutris out!